# 'Can't Recognise as an internal or external command, or batch script.': error running .bat file in Linux

Tags: linux, batch-file, cmd, wine

I am trying to adapt the Zynq BIST file to run on the CENTOS platform I am using, but am rather stuck with the error message I keep receiving. The steps I am taking are as such:

1. Navigate to directory ready_for_download which contains design files download_bit.tcl, system_wrapper.bit, download_elf.tcl and bist_app.elf.
2. Run 'wine cmd'.
3. From Wine, run 'zc706_bist.bat'.

The following is the terminal output:

> Z:\home\recore\Documents\zc706_bist\ready_for_download>call
>   /opt/Xilinx/SDK/2015.1/bin/xmd -tcl download_bit.tcl
>   system_wrapper.bit
>
> Z:\home\recore\Documents\zc706_bist\ready_for_download>/opt/Xilinx/SDK/2015.1/bin/xmd
>   -tcl download_bit.tcl system_wrapper.bit  Can't recognize '/opt/Xilinx/SDK/2015.1/bin/xmd -tcl download_bit.tcl
>   system_wrapper.bit' as an internal or external command, or batch
>   script.
>
> Z:\home\recore\Documents\zc706_bist\ready_for_download>call
>   /opt/Xilinx/SDK/2015.1/bin/xmd -tcl download_elf.tcl bist_app.elf
>
> Z:\home\recore\Documents\zc706_bist\ready_for_download>/opt/Xilinx/SDK/2015.1/bin/xmd
>   -tcl download_elf.tcl bist_app.elf  Can't recognize '/opt/Xilinx/SDK/2015.1/bin/xmd -tcl download_elf.tcl bist_app.elf' as
>   an internal or external command, or batch script.

I have so far tried specifying full pathways in the call function for all the design files as well as file xmd, and have tried changing the pathway format to windows format (Z:\ and \ rather than /), as I am unsure if Wine compensates for this difference naturally. It seems to point towards a syntax/pathway error, although having verified the pathways I feel like I am just missing something, and am quite new to this so am unsure what that could be. Any help is appreciated.

For details, the full file zc706_bist.bat is:

```
call /opt/Xilinx/SDK/2015.1/bin/xmd -tcl download_bit.tcl system_wrapper.bit
call /opt/Xilinx/SDK/2015.1/bin/xmd -tcl download_elf.tcl bist_app.elf
if exist *isWriteableTest*.tmp del /F *isWriteableTest*.tmp
if exist vivado_*.backup.jou del /F vivado_*.backup.jou
if exist vivado_*.backup.log del /F vivado_*.backup.log
if exist vivado_*.str del /F vivado_*.str
pause
```

Comment: Looking at the extension, .bat is a windows batch file. I'm kinda confused here - why you running this in Linux? Another thing is with the path Z:\ - Is this a mapped network drive (samba share) of your Linux machine on Windows?

Comment: @RuncyOommen - Robson defined his steps as running Wine, and the `.bat` file therein.

Comment: @RuncyOommen The .bat file is a self-test script for a board I have just begun using, the manufacturer unfortunately do not supply files for Linux systems. Thought it would be an easy enough script to change to work in Linux, guess I was wrong!

Comment: you cannot mix up wine bat and linux commands. you'd need to call `Z:\opt\..` etc., and also use backslashes